# Parse JSON with multiple objects in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON file with multiple objects by one of the values in the object, however I am not sure if this is possible with my method.

JSON

```
[{"Temp":512,"Name":"sdfd3","SearchTags":["North"]},
[{"Temp":45,"Name":"dfs5","SearchTags":["South"]},
[{"Temp":251,"Name":"sfsd6","SearchTags":["North"]},
```

Python

```
myObj = response.content;

x = json.loads(myObj)


for item in x:
    if myObj(Name) == "dfs5":
        print(Temp, SearchTags)
```

I am new to JSON and Python but cannot seem to find any guidance on searching where a JSON file has multiple lines.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The given JSON file is invalid even considering multiple JSON objects. Square brackets not closed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your JSON object is not correct. Still, I have tried to recreate your issue.

```
myObj = [
    {"Temp":"512","Name":"sdfd3","SearchTags":["North"]},
    {"Temp":45,"Name":"dfs5","SearchTags":["South"]},
    {"Temp":251,"Name":"sfsd6","SearchTags":["North"]}
]

for item in myObj:
    if item.get("Name") == "dfs5":
        print(item["Temp"], item["SearchTags"])
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a test. I have copied the example from a really large JSON file and just checked and I have made a typo when copying, the JSON file is formatted like you have put.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be getting the error below when using the code above. 

   if item.get("Name") == "dfs5":
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Well, I can't recreate your issue so can't say much. Now it seems that you have redefined the ```item``` variable to an int.